# What is problematic about below ocaml code?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

```
let rec funli li k = match li with 
| [x] -> if k==1 then Some(x) else None
| x::ll -> funli ll k-1;;
```

utop shows 
Error: This expression has type 'a option but an expression was expected of type int

I see no reason for it to expect `int`. Please help me understand what is happening in this code. I am new to OCaml.

Comment: Try it with `funli ll (k-1)` in the `x:ll` arm.

Comment: Also, `k==1` is invalid syntax. You want `k=1`. `==` is not used to test equality in OCaml.

Comment: It's not invalid syntax.  But not recommended for integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems with your code. First, you want to be explicit that `k-1` is a parameter and that you're not trying to return `(funli ll k)-1`, which is what OCaml is interpreting that arm as. Additionally, `==` is not used to test equality in OCaml. This will work fine

```
let rec funli li k = match li with 
| [x] -> if k=1 then Some(x) else None
| x::ll -> funli ll (k-1);;
```

Answer (score 0):

`funli ll k-1` is parsed as `(funli ll k)-1`. So you're trying to subtract one from an option, leading to the error you got.

What you want is `funli ll (k-1)`.